# how can i import win32com module in webcompiler (ide.goorm.io) in linux develop envilonment,

Tags: python-3.x, import, win32com

import error in webcomfiler Goorm Linux Envirenment.

I find python library directory and mv win32com folder.(https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)-unzipfile
and excute command_ python setup.py
but Just show error massage like this

Just download zipfile[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fRYM.png)

but when i excute installer file win32com in windows envirenment,there is no problem.
how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

pywin32 is a package of extension modules for accessing Windows C and COM APIs in Windows Python.

You can't install it in Linux Python.